# Basement Ceiling Soundproofing

Tags: framing, joists, sound-proofing

How can I soundproof my basement ceiling?

I was thinking of enclosing the entire basement ceiling with 2x4s to soundproof the floor, will this work?

Comment: The issue is going to be *weight*. A quick search shows a 2x4 at 9 lbs. per 8 ft. That's 3.5" wide. Math...3.5" x 12' = 336 square inches = 9 lbs. That is 2.33 square feet = 9 lbs so 3.9 lbs. per square foot. That's about double what 3/4" plywood (1.9 lbs/square foot) weighs. So a lot of extra weight but not necessarily that bad.

Comment: What? This makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to do? Please explain in greater detail, as it is currently written it's extremely hard to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: @matt. I believe OP wants to lay 2x4s across the basement ceiling/under the main floor above it. Like deck boards.

Comment: So you want to enclose the ceiling by attaching 2x4s to the bottom of the floor joists, for soundproofing? Just trying to understand.

Comment: what do you mean with "Can i frame my entire joist". There are lots of folks here with framing and soundproofing experience eagerly waiting to help you, but clueless as to what you are proposing.

Comment: Please feel free to [edit] your question to provide more details on what you're attempting to do. Also, define "soundproof" - anechoic chambers can cost $100k plus, but they're absolutely silent inside. Adding some sound proofing insulation in the floor can reduce some of the noise transmitted through, but not enough for a recording studio. What's your ultimate goal here? Also, please search through the [tag:sound-proofing] tagged questions as there is already a lot of good general info on this site and pointers to where to go for more research.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that. Weight might be an issue, but probably not too bad. Rough estimate about twice that of 3/4" plywood. But I don't know how *effective* it will be. Generally speaking solid materials will block some sound but are actually good transmitters. What you really want is an air gap or insulated, e.g., fiberglass, gap between the floor and ceiling.

Answer (score 2):

No, I would strongly advise against this for multiple reasons.

1. Little to no soundproofing value.
2. A lot of extra weight added to the floor system.
3. Difficult to gain access to the floor system in the event of an electrical or plumbing issue.

You might consider talking to someone well versed in soundproofing or have someone come out and give you a quote on how to do it properly.

I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to soundproofing methods so I will not attempt to offer a solution that could lead you astray.